# Efeito paginaçao carousel

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-3

Eu estou tentando fazer uma coisa em um trabalho mas não consigo por nada. Preciso fazer conforme a imagem abaixo:

[image: Imagem do site ponto frio]

A parte do "e por isso recomendamos" é recuperado via arquivo json e exibido na tela, tem também essa paginação que eu vi que é feita por bootstrap carousel (desculpe se estiver errado, estou aprendendo isso agora.)

sera que alguém pode me dar uma luz? preciso fazer isso em Html + javascript puro, sem utilização de framework.

Meu problema esta sendo essa paginação e a exibição de uma lista apenas com html e javascritpt.

No html e javascript, tentei colocar mais ou menos dessa forma mas nao esta dando muito certo(esse é um exemplo que peguei)

Javascript:

```
$.getJSON( "products.json", function( data ) {

        // Write the data into our global variable.
        products = data;

        // Call a function to create HTML for all the products.
        generateAllProductsHTML(products);

        // Manually trigger a hashchange to start the app.
        $(window).trigger('hashchange');
    });


    // An event handler with calls the render function on every hashchange.
    // The render function will show the appropriate content of out page.
    $(window).on('hashchange', function(){
        render(decodeURI(window.location.hash));
    });
```

html:

```
<ul class="products-list">
  <script id="products-template" type="x-handlebars-template">​
    {{#each this}}
      <li data-index="{{id}}">
        <a href="#" class="product-photo"><img src="{{image.small}}" height="130" alt="{{name}}"/></a>
        <h2><a href="#"> {{name}} </a></h2>
        <ul class="product-description">
          <li><span>Manufacturer: </span>{{specs.manufacturer}}</li>
          <li><span>Storage: </span>{{specs.storage}} GB</li>
          <li><span>OS: </span>{{specs.os}}</li>
          <li><span>Camera: </span>{{specs.camera}} Mpx</li>
        </ul>
        <button>Buy Now!</button>
        <p class="product-price">{{price}}$</p>
        <div class="highlight"></div>
      </li>
    {{/each}}
  </script>
</ul>
```

Comment: Pra facilitar te ajudarem, adicione também o que você já tentou fazer na pergunta.

Comment: Podes criar um exemplo com o HTML renderizado e/ou que reproduza o problema que precisas de ajuda a ultrapassar?

Comment: Stack Snipet é pra reproduzir códigos, não pra marcação. Se a atente ao uso correto das ferramentas. Leia http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4463/3635 e http://pt.stackoverflow.com/editing-help#comment-formatting